# ERROR 403 (Forbidden) when HTML includes resources like CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, permission-denied

I am getting 403 when loading those files

```html
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.graphalchemist.com/alchemy.0.2.min.css"></link>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.graphalchemist.com/alchemy.0.2.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

[as exemplified](http://graphalchemist.github.io/Alchemy/#/docs)

Yet, to my great surprise, browswer can fetch them if I enter the resource addresses into the address bar manually. How can this be?

Comment: Your stylesheet url leads to javascript. The one in documentation works fine.

Comment: It's fine here - Chrome Version 40.0.2214.93 m

Comment: Try to add to  `<head>` not to `<body>`

Comment: @FlashThunder good spot. This eliminated the CSS issue. But JS is still forbidden (Chrome  40.0.2214.93).

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/nz9Lo44n/show  Chrome 40 - view frame source

Comment: @mplungjan Works what? I see that you load alchemy.min.css instead of alchemy.`0.2`.min.css that I addressed in my question. Surely, it will work.

Comment: @mplungjan They have fixed the page already. You were sleeping too long :)

Comment: I get 403 here http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7tc21g1j/ . So now it is clear

Comment: @mplungjan Wait, no they didn't. It they have both examples, with .min and .0.2.min and I asked about 0.2.min.

Comment: With 0.2 I get I get 
x-amz-error-code:AccessDenied - and the CSS is returned as JS so I suggest you tell them to fix their stuff

Answer (score 0):

The `<link>` tag should be in `<head>`, and then try to add `type="text/css"`at css tag

Comment: This is completely wrong. Files had to be min.css and min.js rather than  `0.2.min`. I think that alchemists have fixed the issue rapidly I reported this in [their issue tracker](https://github.com/GraphAlchemist/Alchemy/issues/343#issuecomment-71804741). This has nothing to do with `head` and `text/javascript.

Comment: Doesn't the page say file names should have the version in their names?

Comment: Where do you see version mismatch? How is this related with my question and your answer?